# CodeIgniter HMVC URL not working on LAMP UBUNTU

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

Helo there..

I cant resolve this, i try another tutorial in my codeigniter.

in XAMPP Windows HMVC CodeIgniter works fine, if I Upload to my vps UBUNTU LAMP, trying .htaccess and apache mod rewrite and still get HMVC error and get URL NOT FOUND , why ? 
if there are errors in my codeigniter ?
or have a another settings ..?

1 question, why LAMP read HMVC plain as html?
thanks b4..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure with the limited info you've provided, but I would say that the first thing to check if you've uploaded the Codeigniter folder to your server would be the permissions of the folder and files inside of it.

This link should tell you everything you need to know about about getting it set up:

http://idroot.net/tutorials/how-to-install-codeigniter-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I already follow this tutorial, 
I'm confused why different xampp with lampp ..?

Comment: For all intents and purposes they are pretty much the same thing, the main difference is that they are installed a bit differently. Of course LAMP stands for "Linux Apache MySQL PHP" and XAMPP stands for "X (crossplatform) Apache MySQL PHP Pearl" so the only real difference is that with XAMPP, Pearl is automatically installed also.

Comment: And did you check the permissions of the web directory folder like it mentioned in the article?